# Expected value of bounded function?

Tags: expected-value, function

The expected value of a function is

$$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x)dx.$$

What happens if $g$ is a function such as $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow]a,b[$? Does the expected value exist? Should I take the integral just as

$$E[g(x)] = \int_{a}^{b}g(x)f(x)dx?$$

Comment: Are you trying to estimate the expected value within the bounds (ie, as it manifests), or of the latent variable?

Comment: No, the second formula is incorrect! If the function $g(x)$ is bounded between $a$ and $b$ for all real $x$, it is true that $a E[X]\leq E[g(X)]\leq b E[X]$.

Comment: @gung within the bounds, I guess (I don't actually understand what you mean by latent variable).

Comment: The latent variable is $g(x)$, the manifest variable is $h(x)=_a]g(x)[_b$.

Comment: The expectation may or may not exist.  It depends on the distribution $f $ as well.  There is no one rule for existence in this general of a context.  You can simulate it to find out and see if the central limit theorem holds up.  Be sure to intergrate over the entire sample space though...not just $a $ to $b $.

Comment: What would happen if $f$ is (say) normally or uniformly distributed?

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld How would I do the simulation?

Comment: Could you please explain what "$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow]a,b[$" means?  The standard mathematical meaning is that $g$ is a fucntion defined on $\mathbb{R}$ with values in the open interval $]a,b[$, but with that interpretation this question is so trivial--as @StijnDeVuyst has pointed out--that we have to assume you mean something else by it. What, exactly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP did not reply to requests for clarification